# Left Outer Join with Multiple On Statements

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I've been on this for hours now. This is what I've tried:

```
List<SoccerTeamsModel> incompleteFootballTeams = (from fbt in db.footballTeams
    join fbct in db.footballCustomTeams
    on fbt.team_id equals fbct.team_id && fbct.client_id == clientId && fbct.language == selectedLanguage into t
    from ct in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where fbt.league_id == leagueId
    orderby fbt.name ascending
    select new SoccerTeamsModel
    {
        TeamId = fbt.team_id,
        ClientId = ct.client_id, 
        etc...
    }).ToList();
```

the SQL query i'm trying to copy:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM [SoccerData].[dbo].[footballTeams] AS fbt
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [SoccerData].[dbo].[footballCustomTeams] AS fbct
  ON fbt.team_id = fbct.team_id AND fbct.client_id = 104 AND fbct.[language] = 'fr-FR'  
  WHERE fbt.league_id = 8
  ORDER BY fbt.name ASC
```

What's messing me up it seems is trying to put in all the multiple "on" clauses. I've seen some examples but they don't include the Left Outer Join. I can't seem to put the two together.

Comment: Instead of cluttering your application code with database queries, why not write a stored procedure and call it from your application's data-access layet?

Comment: @Stan company doesn't want us using stored procedures for this unfortunately

Comment: i ended up going the route of using a literal query string instead of using LINQ.  too complicated imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should provide something close to you SQL expression. It's quite different from your LINQ, but I assumed the result of the SQL is your target:

```
var clientId = 104;
var lang = "fr-FR";
var leagueId = 8;

// Find teams in specifiec league
// Equivalent to this step in SQL: WHERE fbt.league_id = 8
var leagueTeams = footballTeams.Where(fbt => fbt.league_id == leagueId).ToList();

// Find teams that fulfill required conditions
// Equivalent to the On condition in SQL
var teams = footballCustomTeams
.Where(fbct => leagueTeams.Any(fbt => fbct.team_id == fbt.team_id) &&
                fbct.client_id == clientId &&
                fbct.language == lang)
.Select(fbct => new { TeamId = fbct.team_id, ClientId = fbct.client_id });
```

Instead of reproducing the join I simply divided the LINQ query into more subqueries that each narrows the results down. May need slight adjustments as I didn't have access to your model and only tried to infer that from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make those multiple ON statements. That's a poorly formatted SQL statement. The ON should only be the relation between the two tables that are being joined.

Move the `client_id = 104` and `[language] = 'fr-FR'` to additional parts of the WHERE, and you'll be fine.

Comment: that's actually how i originally had it, but i didn't get the results I was looking for until i moved it into the ON part..

Comment: Are the results you get with it as a part of the ON what you should actually be getting? Worst case, you can just use Entity Framework to execute a SQL string directly.

Comment: yes it's exactly what i needed.  i wanted to make sure the results were correct in SQL first before i tried to do it in LINQ.  ya maybe i'll try doing the SQL string directly..

Comment: Can you provide us with the sample data